# JQuery Countdown not working in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, countdown

Why won't this work in IE? I'm using the countdown plugin from Keith Wood, updated the plugin and JQuery. All timers show 00:00 in IE and only the first timer will display.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var i = 0;
        $('.countdown').each(function() {
            var year = $(this).attr('yr');
            var month = $(this).attr('mth') - 1;
            var day = $(this).attr('day');
            var hour = $(this).attr('hr') - 3;
            var minute = $(this).attr('min');
            var second = $(this).attr('sec');
            var ends = new Date();
            ends = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
            $('#countdown_' + i).countdown({until: ends, format: 'MS', compact: true});
            i++;
            console.log("Countdown!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Comment out the console.log

Comment: That fixed the issue with them displaying but they're still all showing 00:00 now.

Answer (score 1):

You are subtracting the hour:

```
var hour = $(this).attr('hr') - 3;
```

I believe, [from the example I see](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html), that using countdown the hour must be greater than the current time.  That would make it less than the current date, and therefore always zero.  Try adding 3 to verify.

Comment: That helped! The only problem is, I had to subtract 3 hrs to get the correct time showing in the Chrome browser. But now Chrome and IE appear to have different timezones since their timers are different. Is there some way to set the timezone for a browser?

Comment: Removing the "-3"  and adding .getUTCHours() at the end of the new Date function fixed it! Thanks for the quick help debugging, I'm surprised it was such a simple fix.